# How to fix this error? Are you running low on disk space? Continuing

Tags: server, steam

I am trying to run an Unturned server with my Ubuntu 16.04.
I followed all steps... http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/Hosting_a_Dedicated_Server ...

```
'/home/steam/serverfiles/Unturned.x86' -port:27017 -players:20 -nographics -pei -gold -pve -sv
```

Found path: /home/steam/serverfiles/Unturned.x86
Mono path[0] = '/home/steam/serverfiles/Unturned_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/home/steam/serverfiles/Unturned_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/home/steam/serverfiles/Unturned_Data/Mono/etc'
Using libudev for joystick management

But I get an error saying...

Couldn't set up the Steam Runtime. Are you running low on disk space?
Continuing...

Couldn't start bootstrap and couldn't reinstall from /usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz.  Please contact technical support.

Can you lease help?

Comment: Well... are you running low on disk space?

Comment: no i have over 500gb left on my hard drive :)